# Problem with distance between two locations using gps in android

Tags: android, gps

I have an activity that shows the current location and the distance with the previous point. I do that in a thread to check every 10 seconds the difference between the two locations, but the problem is that I don´t know why, distance is adding itself. For example, now I´m in place A and I move to place B which is 1 km far from the first point. So distance shows 1000 (meters). but now If I move from place B to place C which is 3 km far from point B, distance shows 4000 meters instead of 3000.

Here´s my thread:

```
class Hilo2 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stepSensorManager.registerListener(listenerStep, stepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            while (contador<30) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            //Toast.makeText(Prueba.this, "Holsss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            obtenerCoordenadas();
                            if(distance>10){
                                recreo.add("SI");
                            }else{
                                recreo.add("NO");
                            }
                            //textViewSteps.setText("Distancia"+currentLocation.distanceTo(previousLocation));
                            contador++;
                            if(contador==10){
                                if(recreo.isEmpty()){

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here´s my obtenerCoordenadas and Listener:

```
private void obtenerCoordenadas() {
        locationListener = new Prueba.MyLocationListener();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
            /*lat.setText("Longitud funcion:" + location.getLongitude());
            lon.setText("Latitud funcion:" + location.getLatitude());*/
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            currentLocation=location;
            previousLocation=currentLocation;

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "sin localizacion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
        }


    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            if (loc != null) {
                // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location changed : Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cambio de localización", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                lat.setText("Longitud onChange:" + loc.getLongitude());
                lon.setText("Latitud onChange:" + loc.getLatitude());

                String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
                Log.v(TAG, longitude);
                String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
                Log.v(TAG, latitude);
                currentLocation=loc;
                distance= (int)currentLocation.distanceTo(previousLocation);
                textView.setText("Distancia: "+distance);
                previousLocation=currentLocation;
                /*lon.setText("Longitude ess: " + loc.getLongitude());
                lat.setText("Latitude ess: " + loc.getLatitude());*/

                /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
                String cityName = null;
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),
                        Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses;
                try {
                    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc
                            .getLongitude(), 1);
                    if (addresses.size() > 0)
                        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            /*String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude +
                    "\n\nMy Currrent City is: " + cityName;
            textViewCiudad.setText(s);*/
            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Prueba.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Prueba.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 00, locationListener);

            }


        }
```

The operation of getting the distance is done in the onLocationChanged method.
Thank you.